# How can I move a person from a DropDownList (the ddl is on table 1 ) to another table (table 2) using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my first post so please be kind with me. :D
What i want is to select a person from a DropDownList (which is on table 1) and when i press a button, I want to move the selected person to another table (on table 2).
I will post some screens from my PC because i cant add code (i receive some error where say is too much code or something like that...)

**Here is the link with Photos. I dont have 10 reputation so i cant post different URL with description...:D**

http://postimg.org/gallery/13lmzz4kq/

I write description in every photo :D

Ty in advance !

Comment: Here is the Plunker link with code :D
http://plnkr.co/edit/gHm9qxhYZr9AfLNgGwXh?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plunker you have a method `moveAudit`. This method receives an item:

```
$scope.moveAudit = function (item) //Function for moving the unassigned audits
{
    //var assignedAudit = $scope.assignedAudit; //--> you dont need this here
    //var audit = $scope.unassignedAudit; //--> unused variable
    //var auditId = $scope.unassignedAudit.IdUnassignedAudit; //--> unused variable

    //TODO: here you need to add the selected 'expert' to item
    // inspect/debug how your form POST passes this information to the controller
    // ideally put it in a scoped var or pass it in the method: $scope.moveAudit = function (item, selectedExpert)
    item.AssignedExpert = $scope.selectedExpert

    //add to AssignedAudit 
    $scope.assignedAudit.push(item);
    console.log("Row added: ", $scope.assignedAudit);

    //TODO: probably you want to remove the item from $scope.assignmentExperts
};
```

I cannot debug the plunker since it is incomplete, but this should do the trick.

Upon further inspection of your code it looks like `$scope.ddSelection` is the selected expert.

Comment: Can you be more explicit please? Because im new with angular :(
And i cant add 2 ul in HTML. The table is standard and cant be modified.
I need somehow to complete the function `$scope.showSelection = function (){ 

}`

Comment: In angular you let the models do the work. Basically the code looks to be written with that intent, so if you update the `item` you're working with and add that to the list your repeater reflects the ui should be updated accordingly.

Comment: You can try to add `$scope.$apply();` to the moveAudit method. See also: [When to use $scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply%28%29) in the docs.